# Realm: updateOrInsert without index

Tags: android, realm

I have a RealmObject, which is used as a temporary data cache only (there will be many entries). I also wrote a static method `add()` so I can easily add a new entry, but it seems too complicated. Here is the whole class:

```
public class ExchangePairPriceCache extends RealmObject {
    @Index
    private String exchangeName;
    @Index
    private String baseCurrency;
    @Index
    private String quoteCurrency;
    private float price;
    private long lastPriceUpdate;

    public ExchangePairPriceCache() {
        exchangeName = "";
        baseCurrency = "";
        quoteCurrency = "";
        price = 0;
        lastPriceUpdate = 0;
    }

    public ExchangePairPriceCache(String exchangeName, String baseCurrency, String quoteCurrency) {
        this.exchangeName = exchangeName;
        this.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
        this.quoteCurrency = quoteCurrency;
        price = 0;
        lastPriceUpdate = 0;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        // this needs to be called inside a Realm transaction if it's a managed object
        this.price = price;
        lastPriceUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /* static functions */
    public static void add(String exchangeName, String baseCurrency, String quoteCurrency, float price) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
            ExchangePairPriceCache priceCache = r.where(ExchangePairPriceCache.class)
                    .equalTo("exchangeName", exchangeName)
                    .equalTo("baseCurrency", baseCurrency)
                    .equalTo("quoteCurrency", quoteCurrency).findFirst();
            if(priceCache != null) {
                priceCache.setPrice(price);
            } else {
                priceCache = new ExchangePairPriceCache(exchangeName, baseCurrency, quoteCurrency);
                priceCache.setPrice(price);
                ExchangePairPriceCache finalPriceCache = priceCache;
                r.insert(finalPriceCache);
            }
        });
        realm.close();
    }

    public static ExchangePairPriceCache get(String exchangeName, String baseCurrency, String quoteCurrency) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        ExchangePairPriceCache priceCache = realm.where(ExchangePairPriceCache.class)
                .equalTo("exchangeName", exchangeName)
                .equalTo("baseCurrency", baseCurrency)
                .equalTo("quoteCurrency", quoteCurrency)
                .greaterThan("lastPriceUpdate", System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)).findFirst();
        if(priceCache != null)
            priceCache = realm.copyFromRealm(priceCache);
        realm.close();

        return priceCache;
    }

    public static void deleteAll() {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(r -> r.delete(ExchangePairPriceCache.class));
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this a good design (having static functions for ease of use)? I like how I can insert new entries into cache like `ExchangePairPriceCache.add("NASDAQ", "AAPL", "USD", 100.5);` and delete all with `ExchangePairPriceCache.deleteAll()` when needed.
2. How can I simplify `add()` function? Right now I check if entry already exists and then update the price and if it doesn't, I create a new object and insert it into Realm. I am not able to use `updateOrInsert` because I don't have unique index for object.

Maybe I am just questioning myself too much and this is all good as it is. But I'd really appreciate some input from experts who use it daily.

Comment: *Is this a good design* no, your model class must not contain any such logic

Comment: But why not or more importantly, how to avoid writing all this code (from `add()`) inside my project whenever I want to add a new `ExchangePairPriceCache`  entry to Realm?

Comment: because it's not the responsibility of the model to know how it is persisted. Do it somewhere else, look up "Repository" for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a "Repository design pattern" with a DAO object (Data Access Object), to do all your read/ write transactions in realm.

Model class should be a blind copy of objects just holding entities.

Since you do not have any unique identifiers, you can try below

1. Cache the Exchange pair in Shared preferences file (if they are added earlier or not)
2. For faster read/writes : Create a temporary unique identifier with a combination of key-value pair that you already have
   eg : (exchangeName + baseCurrency + quoteCurrency) - Cast into proper formats to create some unique key with all these values.

Comment: Thanks for you input! Will look into DAO. Otherwise, 1) The number of these pairs is about 30.000. I don't think SharedPrefs are the right place to save them. 2) This would be a good solution, but I need granularity to search by each of these 3 fields. Rarely do I search by all 3 at once.

Comment: Thanks. For creating a temporary unique identifier,  Even if you want to search by only 1 or two and not all three at once, you can do a findAll() in realm rather than findFirst(), This way you need not check with every 30000 records, but come down to a lot less.

Comment: There can only be one combination of `exchangeName, baseCurrency, quoteCurrency`, that is why I am using `findFirst()`. Are you sure `findAll()` would be faster? Why?